# Check used files in directories with PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

I got a job from another programmer. Unfortunately, libraries are full of test files too and I don't know which ones are actually in used. I'd like to filter this out by looking at the links in the files.

It would be a long time by hand. I wrote a code but did not list all the files in use.

Clean up the root directory would be enough.

Thank you your advice!

```
$files = scandir('/public_html/');

$hrefs = array();

foreach ($files as $file) {

   $info = pathinfo($file);
   if ($info["extension"] == "php") {

      $php = file_get_contents($file);

      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $dom->loadHTML($php);

      $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
          $href = $tag->getAttribute('href');
          $href = basename($href);
          if (is_file($href) && !in_array($href, $hrefs)) {
              $hrefs[] = $href;
          }
      }

      $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('form');
      foreach ($tags as $tag) {
          $href = $tag->getAttribute('action');
          $href = basename($href);
          if (is_file($href) && !in_array($href, $hrefs)) {
              $hrefs[] = $href;
          }
      }

      $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
      foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $href = $tag->getAttribute('src');
        $href = basename($href);
        if (is_file($href) && !in_array($href, $hrefs)) {
            $hrefs[] = $href;
        }
      }

  }

}

print_r($hrefs, true);
```

Comment: so, can you explain what is wrong with this code and what the question is?

Comment: This code working, but not listed all used file. I don't know why... e.g: I have a customer_form.php, this call in action the customer_form_update.php. And this file is missing from the list.

Comment: one thing to note that might be relevant to your issue is the creating of a `new DOMDocument` inside the loop... this could quickly consume all the system resources. YOu only need to create it once and then load new documents on each iteration. Set the timeout too to ensure the script has time to finish processing the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just quickly put the following together to scan a directory & sub-directories to list files according to discovered content within files - it might be of use.

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
set_time_limit( 60 );

/* edit to suit. Choose directory, file extensions and exclusions */
$config=(object)array(
    'directory'     =>  __DIR__,
    'extensions'    =>  array( 'php', 'html', 'htm' ),
    'exclusions'    =>  array(
        'bookmarks_11_01_2019.html',
        'bookmarks_05_01_2019.html'
    )
);


function getnodes($type,$attr){
    /*
        helper function to get $type elements 
        and return attribute $attr
    */
    global $dom;
    global $info;
    global $ext;

    $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName( $type );
    $tmp=[];
    if( $col->length > 0 ){
        foreach( $col as $node ){
            $tmp[]=array(
                $attr   =>  $node->getAttribute( $attr ),
                'file'  =>  $info->getFileName(),
                'dir'   =>  $info->getPathInfo()->getRealPath(),
                'type'  =>  $type,
                'ext'   =>  $ext
            );
        }
    }
    return $tmp;
}


libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$links=[];  

/* create the recusive iterators */
$dirItr=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $config->directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );
foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dirItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST ) as $obj => $info ) {
    if( $info->isFile() ){

        $ext = pathinfo( $info->getFileName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION );

        /* only scan files of specified extensions that are not in the exclusions list */
        if( in_array( $ext, $config->extensions ) && !in_array( $info->getFileName(), $config->exclusions ) ){
            /* load a new file into DOMDocument */
            $dom->loadHTMLFile( $info->getPathName() );

            /* ignore errors */
            libxml_clear_errors();

            /* find elements that may be of interest */
            $links=array_merge( 
                $links,
                getnodes( 'a', 'href' ),
                getnodes( 'form', 'action' ),
                getnodes( 'img', 'src' ),
                getnodes( 'iframe', 'src' )
            );
        }
    }
}

/* display scan results*/
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $links, true ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! I removed the first 3 lines and this work fine! Result is 30018 file. :)